# tuple versus Tuple

Tags: type-conversion, tuples, julia

Why do I get the following different results when converting a vector using either `tuple` or `Tuple`?

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
1
2
3

julia> tuple(a)
([1, 2, 3],)

julia> Tuple(a)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Broadcasting gives the same result though:

```
julia> tuple.(a)
3-element Vector{Tuple{Int64}}:
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)

julia> Tuple.(a)
3-element Vector{Tuple{Int64}}:
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
```

(The latter is not so surprising as it just converts single numbers to tuples.)

(This is Julia 1.6.1.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Tuple` is a type and as with all collections in Julia base, if you pass another collection to it, it creates an instance of that type from the contents of the other collection. So `Tuple([1, 2, 3])` constructs a tuple of the values 1, 2 and 3 just like `Set([1, 2, 3])` constructs a set of those same values. Similarly, if you write `Dict([:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3])` you get a dict that contains the pairs `:a => 1`, `:b => 2` and `:c => 3`. This also works nicely when the argument to the constructor is an iterator; some examples:

```
julia> Tuple(k^2 for k=1:3)
(1, 4, 9)

julia> Set(k^2 for k=1:3)
Set{Int64} with 3 elements:
  4
  9
  1

julia> Dict(string(k, base=2, pad=2) => k^2 for k=1:3)
Dict{String, Int64} with 3 entries:
  "10" => 4
  "11" => 9
  "01" => 1
```

So that's why `Tuple` works the way it does. The `tuple` function, on the other hand, is a function that makes a tuple from its arguments like this:

```
julia> tuple()
()

julia> tuple(1)
(1,)

julia> tuple(1, "two")
(1, "two")

julia> tuple(1, "two", 3.0)
(1, "two", 3.0)
```

Why have `tuple` at all instead of just having `Tuple`? You could express this last example as `Tuple([1, "two", 3.0])`. However, that requires constructing a temporary untyped array only to iterate it and make a tuple from its contents, which is really inefficient. If only there was a more efficient container type that the compiler can usually eliminate the construction of... like a tuple. For that we'd write `Tuple((1, "two", 3.0))`. Which works, but is completely redundant since `(1, "two", 3.0)` is already the tuple you wanted. So why would you use `tuple`? Most of the time you don't, you just use the `(1, "two", 3.0)` syntax for constructing a tuple. But sometimes you want an actual function that you can apply to some values to get a tuple of them—and `tuple` is that function. You can actually make an anonymous function that does this pretty easily: `(args...) -> (args...,)`. You can just think of `tuple` as a handy abbreviation for that function.